# Ubuntu 18.04.1 prints user's password during powering off

Tags: 18.04, password, gdm

Ubuntu prints the user password in the text screen that sometimes appear during power off or switching users.

## TL;DR

This was a question, but after investigation it turned out to be a bug (IMHO). I've reported it on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1814388). Please check there for any updates.

## Original

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (bionic) on an old machine (and maybe I only noticed that because it's a slow machine). I used the installation I got from the official Ubuntu website and I started to suspect of that even before I have installed anything else - but I took some time to believe.

I was not able to reproduce this when using just one user, however, when switching users, logging on and off, every now and then (and during power off) the text screen blinks (before the ubuntu logo with the progress dots), and in the bottom of the services statuses, there you have it: the user password!

There's nothing dodgy installed on this machine.

Here's a picture:

[image]

In this case the password appeared twice. It's hard to believe I have done anything wrong as I just installed the official release.

I'm no Ubuntu specialist. Is that considered normal?

#### **UPDATE 1:**

I found a way to easily test it. After switching users, and running:

```
sudo cat /dev/tty1
```

You can see the last passwords - actually, you can see everything which was typed in the login screen (wrong login attempts as well), which is what's also appearing during power off. I've set up a VM with the same Ubuntu version, but so far I was unable to reproduce it. So now I'm suspicious that one of the apps I've installed is actually the evildoer. I'll continue tests (basically reproducing all the steps in the VM) and post here.

#### **UPDATE 2:**

Installed all the apps, all updates, and performed all the steps I remember I have executed (switching language, configuring input, etc). I just can't reproduce it - yet the faulty machine consistently prints all keys of the login window (and only the from the login window) to `/dev/tty1`.

Maybe the issue lays in some driver that this old machine requires and the VM does not.

Now all I want to do is to explode this machine, but I'll make a bug report first. Then I'll reconfigure this machine from scratch and if it still has the problem, I'll update this.

#### **UPDATE 3:**

So this is the [bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1814388).

#### **UPDATE 4:**

New install on a different machine. 18.04 from canonical, no app installed, all the updates installed - no additional app whatsoever and I was able to reproduce it. However, the symptom does not show on 4.15.0-29-generic **recovery mode**.

Running:

```
sudo lsof /dev/tty1
```

prints two processes, `systemd-l` and `gdm-wayla`.

Yeah, now I'm done with the subject. It is part of Ubuntu and not an external app. I'll pretend that it doesn't exist and consider that I've made my part on reporting the bug.

Comment: I highly think that is not possible as passwords in Linux... are not stored in plain-text.

Comment: That is the boot screen output, and if you modify the boot command line, removing "quiet" and "splash" you will be able to see the lines all the time.  I have only a single user on my system, and so will not be able to verify this password display issue.

Comment: @NerdOfCode I don't think it's stored, my theory is someone forgot a print to console while debugging ... And I would think the same as you if it wasn't me, or if I didn't have installed it from scratch using the oficial release...

Comment: @CharlesGreen Are you using 18.04.1 ? If so, the other users I was using were not even admins, just switching to them and switching back would be enough to test. If you could test it (and then delete the users) I would appreciate!

Comment: Is it possible that you have selected a password, that is the same as some system output text, that is independent of your password? Please change password, and try again.

Comment: @sudodus Please see my update, I was able to see the last passwords and even wrong passwords attempts.

Comment: I think you should write a bug report at Launchpad about this problem. Get a user ID at https://launchpad.net and create a bug report: Run `ubuntu-bug ubuntu` and follow the instructions. (Until we know better, blame `ubuntu`). I think you will get help to give more details about the problem by people who know more about bug reports at Launchpad.

Comment: @sudodus Thanks, will do that. However, as I didn't perform too many steps configuring this machine I'll try those so I can report the bug more consistently.

Comment: What does `uname -r` show? Maybe you are suffering from one of the many problems 4.15.0.-44-generic introduced, one of them being weird behaviour in TTYs.

Comment: @PerlDuck its 4.15.0-45-generic , that would explain it. but how i cannot reproduce it in the VM?

Comment: No idea about the VM behaviour. Can you select kernel *-43 at boot time? That one didn't have the TTY problems.

Comment: @PerlDuck the *-29 was available, booted with it and it behaves the same! :(

Comment: Then I don't know. Sorry. :-( The kernel thing was just an idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89192/discussion-between-feu-and-perlduck).

Comment: To get past the problem see: [Ubuntu 18.04 crashes after Guest Addons installed VB5.2.10](https://www.reddit.com/r/virtualbox/comments/8flg3x/ubuntu_1804_crashes_after_guest_addons_installed/) and try unchecking `Enable 3D Acceleration` in `Settings` -> `Display`.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix , but it's not that.

Answer (score 1):

New here but found your problem very interesting. I believe, if you are in fact telling the truth, then some program you have installed or opened just one time has installed something of the following. To record when you enter your password.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device

Not sure if you can search the contents of each file but something like the following is what I would look for. And if you're up for a challenge, try to create one yourself, to gather that info, and that might help you find the culprit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    
int main() {
    char byte;
    int fd = open("/dev/pts/3", O_RDWR);
    write(fd, "X", 1);
    ssize_t size = read(fd, &byte, 1);
    printf("Read byte %c\n", byte);
    return 0;
}
```

Good Luck!

Denis

Comment: Thanks for the insight, your comment made me have an idea and then I learned about the `lsof` command, which shows which processes are using a given resource (such as `/dev/tty1/`. Please read my update 4, I'm aware that not many people will believe me, but I'm convinced it's not an external app.